# Excel: How to dynamically load data from one tab, and display in another sorted differently?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Assume I have two tabs. One that has Data, and the other a Sorted Summarized view.

The Data tab has a bunch of columns for misc data I don't need on the summarized view

The Summary tab wants to take 3 of those columns, and sort the rows by 1 of the columns from Data.

In the data tab, I have a "score" column for each row. New items will get added to the Data list, and the data tab will be sorted by Date of request.

However, in the Summary view, things are sorted by the Score value.

1. I want to be able to add new rows to the data column or make edits to the items in the Data column and have those changes be reflected in the Summary column.
2. I'll need the "header" to stay at the top of the page, and just sort rows 2 on down...
3. I'll need to "carry over" a "description" column, and a "Business Unit" column from the data tab into the summary tab.

Comment: Sounds to me like you can do this with a PivotTable?!

Comment: Yep. Sounds like a job for pivot table.

Comment: Don't pivot tables just sum the data? If I want to take 2 columns of text, and 1 of priority into the summary table ... how can a Pivot table do this?

Comment: No you don't have to sum. There are many operations possible, one of which is "value".

Comment: I have no idea how PivotTables can accomplish this. The "Values" only has sum based options. I need three columns of data, none of which would be a summarized in anyway.

Comment: could you show us an example of what you'd need? And also show, what have already done?

Answer (score 1):

Pivot table has row labels, column labels and values.

put  "carry over" , "description" and  "Business Unit" into column label and "score" into values

you can use many aggregate function in values field.